# How to add a CSS class to field label and items div?

Tags: entities, theming

I want to add a class in the field label and field items, the HTML I want is the following:

```
<div class="field field-name-field-price field-type-number-integer field-label-above row">
            <div class="field-label col-md-2">Price:&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="field-items col-md-2"><div class="field-item even">100</div></div>
</div>
```

I've tried field_formatter_class, the module allow me to add a "row" class into the container, but not in **field-label** and **field-items**. I want to add col-md-2 class for such two divs

How to do that without writing a module to do that?

Answer (score 1):

have you try `hook_preprocess_field()`.

please check this link everything is given in this blog may be it help you
http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/adding-css-classes-fields-drupal

Comment: Please expand your answer. As it's now it's just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using views? If so, you can easily add the class by using the **Style settings** available in **Configure field** options

[image]

Hope this helps!